# R scraper - how to find entry with missing data

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

**Problem:**
During **scraping** from webpage (imdb.com, webpage with film details) there is error message displayed. When I have checked in details, I have noticed that there is no data available for some of the entries.
How to figured out during scraping for which line there is no data and how to fill it with NA?

**Manual investigation:**
I have checked on webpage manually, and problem is with the rank number 1097 where there is only film genre available and there is no runtime.

**Tried:**
to add if entering the 0, but it is added to the last line, not to the title which is missing the value.

**Code:**

```r
#install packages
install.packages("rvest")
install.packages("RSelenium")
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

#open browser (in my case Firefox)
rD <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"))
remDr <- rD[["client"]]

#set variable for the link
ile<-seq(from=1, by=250, length.out = 5)

#create empty frame
filmy_df=data.frame()

#empty values
rank_data<-NA;link<-NA;year<-NA;title_data<-NA;description_data<-NA;runtime_data<-NA;genre_data<-NA

#loop reading the data from each page
for (j in ile){
  #set link for browser
  newURL<-"https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="
  startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)
  
#open link
remDr$navigate(startNumberURL)

#read webpage code
strona_int<-read_html(startNumberURL)

#empty values
rank_data<-NA;link<-NA;year<-NA;title_data<-NA;description_data<-NA;runtime_data<-NA;genre_data<-NA

#read rank
rank_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-primary')
#convert text
rank_data<-html_text(rank_data)
#remove the comma for thousands
rank_data<-gsub(",","",rank_data)
#convert numeric
rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)

#read link for each movie
link<-url_absolute(html_nodes(strona_int, '.lister-item-header a')%>%html_attr(.,'href'),"https://www.imdb.com")

#release year
year<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-year')
#convert text
year<-html_text(year)
#remove non numeric
year<-gsub("\\D","",year)
#set factor
year<-as.factor(year)

#read title
title_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-header a')
#convert text
title_data<-html_text(title_data)
#title_data<-as.character(title_data)

#read description
description_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.ratings-bar+ .text-muted')
#convert text
description_data<-html_text(description_data)
#remove '\n'
description_data<-gsub("\n","",description_data)
#remove space
description_data<-trimws(description_data,"l")

#read runtime
runtime_data <- html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-muted .runtime')
#convert text
runtime_data <- html_text(runtime_data)
#remove min
runtime_data<-gsub(" min","",runtime_data)
length_runtime_data<-length(runtime_data)
#if (length_runtime_data<250){ runtime_data<-append(runtime_data,list(0))}
runtime_data<-as.numeric(runtime_data)


#temp_df
filmy_df_temp<-data.frame(Rank=rank_data,Title=title_data,Release.Year=year,Link=link,Description=description_data,Runtime=runtime_data)

#add to df
filmy_df<-rbind(filmy_df,filmy_df_temp)
}

#close browser
remDr$close()
#stop RSelenium
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

**Error message displayed:**

"Error in data.frame(Rank = rank_data, Title = title_data, Release.Year = year,  :
arguments imply differing number of rows: 250, 249"

Runtime_data contains only 249 entries instead of 250, and there is no runtime data for last line (instead for the line where it is really missing).

---

**Update**
I have found interesting think which maybe can help to solve the problem.
Please check the pictures.
[Anima - source of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91eaH.jpg)
[Knocked Up - next entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziiNC.jpg)

When we compare the pictures, we can notice that Anima, which is causing the problem with runtime_data, do not have html_node containing runtime at all.

So question: is there a way to check if html_node exists or not? If yes, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Stackoverflow you will find everything.
You just need to know how to search and search answer.
Here is the link to the answer for my problem: [Scraping with rvest: how to fill blank numbers in a row to transform in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45723085/scraping-with-rvest-how-to-fill-blank-numbers-in-a-row-to-transform-in-a-data-f)

In short: instead of using html_nodes, html_node (without s) should be used.

```r
#read runtime
runtime_data <- html_node(szczegoly_filmu,'.text-muted .runtime')
#convert to text
runtime_data <- html_text(runtime_data)
#remove " min"
runtime_data<-gsub(" min","",runtime_data)
runtime_data<-as.numeric(runtime_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't run into this problem if you have structured your program a little different. In general, it is better to split your program into logically separate chunks that are more or less independent from each other instead of doing everything at once. That makes debugging much easier.

First, **scrape** the data and store it in a list – use `lapply` or something similar for that.

```
newURL <- "https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?title_type=feature&release_date=,2018-12-31&count=250&start="

pages <- lapply(ile, function(j) {   #set link for browser
   
    startNumberURL<-paste0(newURL,j)

    #open link
    remDr$navigate(startNumberURL)

    #read webpage code
    read_html(startNumberURL)
})
```

Then you have your data scraped and you can take all the time you need to analyse and filter it, without having to start the reading process again. For example, define the function as follows:

```
parsuj_strone <- function(strona_int) {

  #read rank
  rank_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-primary')

  #convert text
  rank_data<-html_text(rank_data)

  #remove the comma for thousands
  rank_data<-gsub(",","",rank_data)

  #convert numeric
  rank_data<-as.numeric(rank_data)

  #read link for each movie
  link<-url_absolute(html_nodes(strona_int, '.lister-item-header a')%>%html_attr(.,'href'),"https://www.imdb.com")

  #release year
  year<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-year')

  #convert text
  year<-html_text(year)

  #remove non numeric
  year<-gsub("\\D","",year)

  #set factor
  year<-as.factor(year)

  #read title
  title_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.lister-item-header a')

  #convert text
  title_data<-html_text(title_data)

  #read description
  description_data<-html_nodes(strona_int,'.ratings-bar+ .text-muted')

  #convert text
  description_data<-html_text(description_data)

  #remove '\n'
  description_data<-gsub("\n","",description_data)

  #remove space
  description_data<-trimws(description_data,"l")

  #read runtime
  runtime_data <- html_nodes(strona_int,'.text-muted .runtime')

  #convert text
  runtime_data <- html_text(runtime_data)

  #remove min
  runtime_data<-gsub(" min","",runtime_data)
  length_runtime_data<-length(runtime_data)

  runtime_data<-as.numeric(runtime_data)

  #temp_df
  filmy_df_temp<- data.frame(Rank=rank_data,Title=title_data,Release.Year=year,Link=link,Description=description_data,Runtime=runtime_data)
  return(filmy_df_temp)

}
```

Now, apply the function to each scraped web site:

```
pages_parsed <- lapply(pages, parsuj_strone)
```

And finally put them together in the data frame:

```
pages_df <- Reduce(rbind, pages_parsed)
```

`Reduce` won't mind an occasional NULL. Powodzenia!

**EDIT**: OK, so the problem is in the `parsuj_strone()` function. First, replace the final line of that function by this:

```
filmy_df_temp<- list(Rank=rank_data, 
                     Title=title_data, 
                     Release.Year=year, Link=link, 
                     Description=description_data, 
                     Runtime=runtime_data)
return(filmy_df_temp)
```

Run

```
pages_parsed <- lapply(pages, parsuj_strone)
```

Then, identify which of the 5 web sites returned problematic entries:

```
sapply(pages_parsed, function(x) sapply(x, length))
```

This should give you a 5 x 6 matrix. Finally, pick an element which has only 249 entries; how does it look? Without knowing your parser well, this at least should give you a hint where the problems may be.

Comment: Executing ```r strony_parsowane<-lapply(kod_strony, parsuj_strone)``` returns same error. I'm guessing that problem is not in adding to the frame, but in the data which should be added to the frame, that they are not equal.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, I don't know your parser / scraper. Does it mean that each time you are navigating to an URL you are getting 250 web sites? Sorry, that is not clear from your code. In that case you need to take a look which of the columns is of unequal length and deal with it.

Comment: Web page which I'm scraping contains 250 entries. And for some of the entries there are missing data which I'm scraping. Then instead of 250, I'm receiving less in each execution. How to find for which entry data is missing and fill it with NA.

Comment: See edit. The problem is, I can't run the Rselene on my machine For Reasons.

Comment: The code which I'm using is not setting Selenium on your machine, but using the remote server. No need to download, install or unpack anything. Just need to use correct browser :)
And I know which one is returning error whithin this 5. But rather to find it and update manually, I would like to update it dynamically during code execution as I will be scrapping lot more than 5 pages. It's just for test.

Comment: Please tell me how `rsDriver` is *not* starting a selenium server on the local machine, I dare you. And yes, of course it is setting up a selenium environment on your local machine. Read the documentation of Rselenium if you don't believe me. But the main reason is that I am running my R in carefully set up conda environments and running RSelenium from them would not be straightforward, taking up much time than I am willing to invest in your problem.

Comment: As I know to start RSelenium locally you need to download jar file, execute it, and in R code use port number. You also need to download correct webdriver. This part of the code you are not dowloading and not staring RSelenium server. So I do not think that it is running locally.
```#remote driver
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
                      port = 4444,
                      browserName = "chrome")```

Comment: Well, I am fairly sure it is running locally. Rselenium does that for you automatically: it downloads everything you need and starts the server for you. Read the docs or scan your ports if you doubt me. And yes, you *could* start it manually and then tell Rselenium to use the running instance instead of launching another process. But if you don't, it starts a server for you.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I'm not so exp in this matter. What I have noticed is that RSelenium is not required to gather this data from the webpage. If possible, try to review my code without setting up RSelenium.